# Service bus caused w3wp to crash

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

Our web app uses Azure Service Bus to communicate any cache changes. Upon start up it subscribes to a topic, and if it receives a message it will invalidate the cache. From time to time we will have timeout issues on the service bus which our app handles gracefully. However, on rare occasions our web app crashes completely. We traced the error down to the following:

```
Application: w3wp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
   at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdGetSiteNameFromId(IntPtr, UInt32, IntPtr ByRef, Int32 ByRef)
   at System.Web.Configuration.ProcessHostConfigUtils.GetSiteNameFromId(UInt32)
   at System.Web.Configuration.ProcessHostMapPath.MapPathCaching(System.String, System.Web.VirtualPath)
   at System.Web.Configuration.ProcessHostMapPath.System.Web.Configuration.IConfigMapPath2.MapPath(System.String, System.Web.VirtualPath)
   at System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationHost.IsConfigRecordRequired(System.String)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.hlNeedsChildFor(System.String)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigRoot.GetConfigRecord(System.String)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigRoot.GetUniqueConfigRecord(System.String)
   at System.Web.Configuration.HttpConfigurationSystem.GetUniqueConfigRecord(System.String)
   at System.Web.CachedPathData.Init(System.Web.CachedPathData)
   at System.Web.CachedPathData.GetConfigPathData(System.String)
   at System.Web.Configuration.HttpConfigurationSystem.GetApplicationSection(System.String)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(System.String)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings()
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SoapProtocolDefaults.IsAvailableClientCertificateThumbprint(System.String ByRef)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.NetMessagingTransportSettings..ctor()
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.NetMessagingTransportSettings.Clone()
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingFactorySettings..ctor(Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingFactorySettings)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingFactorySettings.Clone()
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.BeginReceiveCommand(Microsoft.ServiceBus.Tracing.TrackingContext, Int32, System.TimeSpan, System.String, System.TimeSpan, System.AsyncCallback, System.Object)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver+ReceiveAsyncResult.<GetAsyncSteps>b__25(ReceiveAsyncResult, System.TimeSpan, System.AsyncCallback, System.Object)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].EnumerateSteps(CurrentThreadType<System.__Canon>)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Start()
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.OnBeginTryReceive(Microsoft.ServiceBus.Tracing.TrackingContext, Int32, System.TimeSpan, System.AsyncCallback, System.Object)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver+RetryReceiveAsyncResult.<GetAsyncSteps>b__85(RetryReceiveAsyncResult, System.TimeSpan, System.AsyncCallback, System.Object)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].EnumerateSteps(CurrentThreadType<System.__Canon>)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Start()
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.BeginTryReceive(Microsoft.ServiceBus.Tracing.TrackingContext, Int32, System.TimeSpan, System.AsyncCallback, System.Object)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceivePump+PumpAsyncResult.<GetAsyncSteps>b__1a(PumpAsyncResult, System.TimeSpan, System.AsyncCallback, System.Object)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].EnumerateSteps(CurrentThreadType<System.__Canon>)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].StepCallback(System.IAsyncResult)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.AsyncCompletionWrapperCallback(System.IAsyncResult)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.TryComplete(Boolean, System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean, System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver+RetryReceiveAsyncResult+<GetAsyncSteps>d__97.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].EnumerateSteps(CurrentThreadType<System.__Canon>)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].StepCallback(System.IAsyncResult)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.AsyncCompletionWrapperCallback(System.IAsyncResult)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.TryComplete(Boolean, System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean, System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].EnumerateSteps(CurrentThreadType<System.__Canon>)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].StepCallback(System.IAsyncResult)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.AsyncCompletionWrapperCallback(System.IAsyncResult)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.TryComplete(Boolean, System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean, System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement+ReconnectChannelFactory`1+RequestSessionChannel+RequestAsyncResult+<GetAsyncSteps>d__11[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].EnumerateSteps(CurrentThreadType<System.__Canon>)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].StepCallback(System.IAsyncResult)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.AsyncCompletionWrapperCallback(System.IAsyncResult)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.TryComplete(Boolean, System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean, System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].HandleException(System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].StepCallback(System.IAsyncResult)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.AsyncCompletionWrapperCallback(System.IAsyncResult)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.TryComplete(Boolean, System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean, System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement+ReconnectChannelFactory`1+RequestSessionChannel+RequestAsyncResult+<GetAsyncSteps>d__11[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].EnumerateSteps(CurrentThreadType<System.__Canon>)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].StepCallback(System.IAsyncResult)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.AsyncCompletionWrapperCallback(System.IAsyncResult)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.TryComplete(Boolean, System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean, System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement+DuplexRequestSessionChannel+DuplexCorrelationAsyncResult.TryComplete(Boolean, System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.IOThreadScheduler+ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.Fx+IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
```

It looks like a lot of internal code as at no point in the stack trace could I find code that my app initiate explicitly. I also looks like it's trying to get configuration from AppSettings but somehow got itself involved in unsafe methods, causing an AccessViolationException. The only clue I have is we store the SB end point connection string in connectionStrings rather than appSettings in web.config.

Is there a way to avoid this error in the future?